# How can I insert a box and put my code into it in Latex?

Tags: latex

I've this ASN.1 code into my latex document:

```
\begin{verbatim}
...my code...
\end{verbatim}
```

All I want to do is simply put this code into a box, a square box. How can I do it? Thank you everybody

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: the `fancyvrb` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
...my code...
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need anything more complicate, have a look at `listings` or `minted`